# Finding two files with some common numbers between multiple files

Tags: ubuntu

I have a lots of files example: RT_1.txt, RT_2.txt,....and RT_1000.txt and also other files like: EU_1.txt, EU_2.txt,..... and EU_1000.txt.

I need to use loop in order to put each two files with the same number(like : RT_1.txt and EU_1.txt)in a directory. I am thankful if anyone respond me.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to move the files even if only one of them exists, and assuming as well that the target directory name is the number itself:

```
for n in {1..1000}; do
    mkdir TARGET_$n
    mv -f {RT,EU}_$n.txt TARGET_$n/
done
```

If you only want to move files if both exist, use

```
for n in {1..1000}; do
    [ -e RT_$n.txt ] && [ -e EU_$n.txt ] && \
        mkdir TARGET_$n && mv -f {RT,EU}_$n.txt TARGET_$n/
done
```

instead.

---

Both solutions use the `{1..1000}` construct to generate a list of numbers, and then process the corresponding files. The first block might throw error messages if a file doesn't exist (because it doesn't check whether a file with a specific name does exist at all), the second one tests for existence before creating the target folder and moving the files there.

Comment: Thank you Patrix for your response. I do not get them moved to their corresponding TARGET directories. The script just creates 1000 folders. I tried to replace the last && by || or modify the script a bit but was not successful yet. Do you have other idea? Appreciated.

Comment: Leave out the `-f` in `mv ...`, replace `{1..1000}` with `{1..10}` (so you don't have to delete 1000 directories again) and rerun. Should give you an error message for the `mv` then.

Comment: And just to confirm: the current directory is the one containing the files, and they are named as described in the question (`RT_123.txt`, `EU_42.txt` etc)?

Comment: Right, all those files (RT_123.txt, Eu_42.txt .....) are in current directory. I removed -f, but still nothing changed.

Comment: Patrix, I wonder if I do not need another loop for reading all files before loop for n?

Comment: You don't need to read the file (names), the names get generated automatically. You are using the first code bock, I assume. If `mv` doesn't show an error message the files *do* exist and get moved. Strange. What is the result of `ls -l RT_1.txt RT_99.txt`?

Comment: Ah, and you are using `bash` I assume?

Comment: Yes, I am using bash.